# How to add a custom field output to to each product in the related products section in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So using related.php inside single-product dir in the main theme directory so as to avoid overwriting on updates Im trying to find a way to show a custom field on each related product.

```
<div class="related products">

    <h2><?php _e( 'You might also like...', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

</div>
```

Im guessing and have tried various things to avoid using the default template somewhere here.

```
<?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

by doing

```
  <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

            <div> 
                            <?php the_title(); ?> 
                            /// output image
                            /// out put custom field from each product
                            </div>


        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'You might also like...', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<div id="grid-wrapper">
<div id="the-grid">
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
                <?php //wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
<div class="grid-rect iso isotope-item">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <!-- get product url -->
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();}?> <!-- get product image -->
<h3><?php echo the_title() . " by, " . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-bb_author', true ); ?></h3> <!-- get tiel and author from custom field -->
</a>
</div>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
</div> <!-- end of the-grid -->
</div> <!-- end of grid wrapper -->
    </div> <!-- end of related -->

<?php endif;
```